# Map one graph to another graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

consider we have a flow network $G = \{V_g, E_g\}$ and an undirected graph $T = \{V_t, E_t\}$. Nodes of the network G have weights $w(v): v \in V_g$ and edges G have weights $w(u,v): u,v \in E$. Nodes of the graph T have capacities $c(v): v \in T$ and edges of T have capacities $c(u,v): u,v \in T$.

The task is to assign nodes of G to nodes of T, so that capacities of the nodes and edges of T are not exceeded. Map function can be written as follows:

$$ f: u \mapsto V, u \in T, V \subseteq G$$

These conditions should hold:
$$\sum_{v \in f(u)} w(v) \leq c(u), u \in T$$
$$\sum_{(v_1, v_2) \in \left( f(u_1) \times f (u_2) \right) \cap E_g}w(v_1, v_2) \leq c(u_1, u_2) , u_1 \in T, u_2 \in T $$

For me it is not decided yet, but I also want to optimize certain parameters of resulting map, like, for instance, maximization of residual flow in T.

I'm sorry for not doing exhaustive search in the literature, but I'd like to ask you for an advice or a reference which can direct me to right source of such algorithms.

More specifically the questions are: Which kinds of algorithms can do such a mapping? What is the name for the problem described above?

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the weights, you have what is known as the [Subgraph Isomorphism Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem). Unfortunately, it's NP-complete in general, so there's probably no quick way to solve it.

If there's anything special about your graphs, you should mention it. Sometimes that can make a difference.

Comment: NP is not an issue. At least that what I would expect. I hope to get some heuristic. Graph T is in general a processor topology graph, so you can expect more or less regular. Sometimes T even can be a regular graph in case of n-dimensional torus.

Comment: And I don't think it is a graph isomorphism problem, because I definitely know that G and T are not isomorphic.

Comment: Regular graphs are the worst case for subgraph isomorphism. (And note that I'm not assuming that G and T are isomorphic; this is the **sub**graph isomorphism problem.)

Comment: @mcsim did you get the heuristic?

Comment: I did not. Maybe some simple iterative algorithm will work.